# Jenkins job failed Gateway timeout

Tags: jenkins

I am new in jenkins.

If i correct understand plugin try to request information from some resource, and resource not answer during 60 sec and jenkins fails with timeout.

How can i increase timeout and where can i do this?

2023-08-13 16:52:51,373 INFO : Retrieve scripts content.

2023-08-13 16:53:51,652 WARN : The request has reached the gateway timeout. Lets try again once

2023-08-13 16:54:51,956 ERROR: PrepareEnvironment Error.

JenkinsRest.JenkinsClientRequestGateWayTimeOutException: The request http://XXXXX/plugin/

testautomationplatform/XXXXXXXXXX

has failed with status code GatewayTimeout and description

Gateway Timeout. Response content : java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

```
           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)

           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)

           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you!